# Python escaping variables and text to log file

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to send a mixture of variables and text to a log file via bash's `echo` command. But somehow I am screwing up the escape sequences. Also these variables/strings need to be separated with a `,` (comma) in order to be opened in a spreadsheet (CSV).

```
import os

start_time = "10:00:00"
end_time = "11:00:00"

send_to_log = 'echo "START TIME:,"'+start_time+'",END TIME:,"'+end_time+' >> my_log_file.log
os.system(send_to_log)
```

Now at the moment the whole `send_to_log` variable is just echoed exactly with all the `"` and `'`'s and the variables are not substituted/escaped.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. `os.system(send_to_log)` produces `START TIME:,10:00:00,END TIME:,11:00:00`

Comment: ... Though using `os.system()` to write a string is pretty wacky. Usually that would be done using `with open('my_log_file.log', 'a') as log: log.write('"START_TIME:",{},"END_TIME:",{}\n'.format(start_time, end_time)` with some speculation still as to where exactly you want or don't want quotes.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using bash and not e.g the logging library? - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

start_time = "10:00:00"
end_time = "11:00:00"

msg = f'"START TIME:,{start_time},END TIME:,{end_time}"'
send_to_log = f'echo {msg} >> my_log_file.log'
os.system(send_to_log)
```